# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having a trouble with figuring out what "this spsefic outcome" in Google PageSpeed Test actually mean.

I am testing this website: www.loaistudio.com - https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?url=www.loaistudio.com

[image: screenshot of test result]

Can anyone advice me please? I have managed to fix all of the other errors - but I am completely stuck at this one, I understand that CSS has to be in the head of the page, is this telling not to place it in the head but at the end of the page?!

Comment: Some advise that you put the javascript resources like jQuery and the like at the end of the page just before the closing `</body>` tags, this is how the bootstrap framework does it, although the advantage is minimal.

Comment: Aren't those blue headings links pointing to help sites?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Your browser freezes page rendering while loading JavaScript

**Quick answer: you just have to put your JavaScript src below your content.**

Why? Because when your browser begins loading JavaScript, it freezes the rest until it's done with that.

Loading the content of your page first allows it to be displayed, and then JavaScript has all the time it needs to load.

So do like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        My great body content!
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my/js/files.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleapi.com/my/external/scripts.js">
    </body>
</html>
```

Instead of this (which is unfortunately still really common):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="my/js/files.js">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.googleapi.com/my/external/scripts.js">
    </head>
    <body>
        My great body content!
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This worked, but CSS? why is it telling me to put it at the end as well!? That can't be done right? CSS always has to be in the top?

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, just add the async at the end of your script tag.

```
<script src='' async></script>
```

Comment: If only life were that easy!  This is a dangerous method to employ as it assumes two things 1) the browser supports async 2) that there is no dependency between scripts loaded with async. For example, what if you load jQuery with async and your own script (which uses jQuery) loads before it? Answer: errors.