# Contact form does not validate on an iphone

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iphone

The following contact form is not validating when submitting from an iphone... 
It can be previewed here: [loaistudio.com/contact](http://loaistudio.com/contact)

When I tried to submit the form without felling the fields, it opened a new blank page showing number 1 only on the top left side "which is not suppose to do at all" and actually sent the form empty... It does not do that on desktop.

I played around with the code trying to find the issue but no idea where is the problem! please help.

```
   <?php
       session_start();

       if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST'){
          ob_start();

          if(isset($_POST['name'])
          && isset($_POST['email'])
          && isset($_POST['message'])
          && isset($_POST['token'])){

             if($_SESSION['token'] != $_POST['token']){
                $response = "0";
             } else {
                $_SESSION['token'] = "";
                $name = $_POST['name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $message = $_POST['message'];

                $to = "EMAIL GOES HERE";
                $subject = "New Message From: $name";
                $message = "$message";

                $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8' . "\r\n";
                $headers .= 'From: '.$email . "\r\n";
                $mailed = ( mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers) );

                if( isset($_POST['ajax']))$response = ($mailed) ? "1" :
                "0"; else $response = ($mailed) ? "<h2>Success!</h2>" :
                "<h2>Error! There was a problem with sending.</h2>";
                echo $response;
             }

          } else {
             echo "Form data error!";
          }

          ob_flush();
          die();
       }

    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html class="no-js">
    <head>
       <title>Contact us | Website</title>
    </head>

    <body>
          <div class="wrapper" id="contactPage">
             <div class="content">

                <?php
                   $token = md5(uniqid(rand(), TRUE));
                   $_SESSION['token'] = $token;
                ?>

                <!--Contact Form-->
                <form action="contact.php" id="contactForm" method="post" name="contactForm">
                   <input name="token" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $token; ?>">
                   <input name="ajax" type="hidden" value="1">

                   <div class="name">
                      <p>Your Name</p>
                      <input name="name" placeholder="Enter Name" required="" type="text">
                   </div>

                   <div class="email">
                      <p>Email Address</p>
                      <input name="email" placeholder="Enter Email" required="" type="email">
                   </div>

                   <div class="message">
                      <p>Message</p>
                      <textarea name="message" required=""></textarea>
                   </div>

                   <button id="submit" type="submit">Send</button>
                </form>

                <script type="text/javascript">
                   $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {

                      event.preventDefault();
                      $submit = $(this).find('button[id="submit"]');
                      var posting = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $('#contactForm').serialize());

                      posting.done(function(data) {
                         $('span.error').remove();

                         if (data == "1") {
                            $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
                            $submit.addClass("sent");
                            $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                         } else {
                            $submit.after('<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 15px 5px; color: #bd3d3d">Failed to send the message, please try again later.</span>');
                            $submit.text('Try Again');
                         }
                      });
                   });
                </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I just submitted a non-empty form and got a '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are adding jquery at the end of the html but you are using jquery before that, so javascript breaks with `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined`.
try moving this line to header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The reason I placed it at the bottom is because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21540258/eliminate-render-blocking-javascript-and-css?noredirect=1#comment32528686_21540258

Comment: then either put your javacript BELOW jquery definiton or run it on body onload like this `<body onload='runOnLoad()'>`
`function runOnLoad() {$("#contactForm").submit(....`

Comment: javascript is a structural scripting language. which means the order which you place your code matters. that is why they advised you to put that code at the end. this way even if the jquery script cannot be loaded right away your whole html/css could be loaded, so user could see the result i.e. no waiting for scripts to load. but that doesn't mean you could put plain jquery code scattered around your html file.

Comment: So I have to place the contact JS at the end as well?

Comment: yes. after `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>` line

Comment: There is no way to keep it there mate? is that the only solution?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46762/discussion-between-loai-and-volkan-ulukut)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           $("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {

              event.preventDefault();
              $submit = $(this).find('button[id="submit"]');
              var posting = $.post($(this).attr('action'), $('#contactForm').serialize());

              posting.done(function(data) {
                 $('span.error').remove();

                 if (data == "1") {
                    $submit.text('Sent. Thank You!');
                    $submit.addClass("sent");
                    $submit.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
                 } else {
                    $submit.after('<span style="display: inline-block; padding: 15px 5px; color: #bd3d3d">Failed to send the message, please try again later.</span>');
                    $submit.text('Try Again');
                 }
              });
           });
        </script>
```

This is code You have added AND THEN INCLUDED JQUERY, :) SO USE JQUERY IN HEADER !

Comment: Don't understand? do I need to move the whole thing to the header? even the links to the JS Library?

Comment: Do 2 steps=> 1) Move this to header after including jquery1.10.js =>       <script type="text/javascript" src="Contact%20us%20_%20Website_files/main.js"></script>
<script src="Contact%20us%20_%20Website_files/modernizr.js"></script>     step 2=>Now Put that long <script> </script> code after Form to the place juet before </body> tag